# Two integer values of same value when compared says they're not equal

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I recently learned a bit of python. Im trying to make a number guessing game on a frame widget. Random Number button is pressed to generate a random number. The Enter button then takes the input from the Entry Box and compares to the random number generated. To test it the program a label that shows the random number generated. When i input the same number as the one generated it says its not equal. The only time it says its equal is when i input 0(zero). I also have some lines that tell me what type the values are just to make sure I'm comparing the same types.

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Guess Number Final')
root.geometry('500x500')



directionFrame = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 200, highlightbackground = 'red', 
highlightthickness = 3)
directionFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 20, ipadx = 20, ipady = 20)

randomNum = IntVar()
newguessInt = IntVar()

def randomize():

     randomNum = randint(0,10)
     randomStr.set(randomNum)


def enterGuess():

    newguessInt = int(number_input.get())

    newRandom = randomNum.get()

    if (newguessInt == newRandom):

        guess_var.set('Your guess is right.')

    else:

         guess_var.set('Your guess is wrong.')


    guess_str.set(type(newguessInt))
    random_str.set(type(newRandom))

##### Random Button #####

randomBtn = Button(directionFrame, text = 'Random Number', command = randomize)
randomBtn.pack()


##### Random Variable #####

randomStr = StringVar()
randomStr.set('Number')

##### Guess Variable #####

guess_var = StringVar()
guess_var.set('Your guess is...')


##### typeGuessVariable #####

guess_str = StringVar()
guess_str.set('Type')

##### randomNumVariable #####

random_str = StringVar()
random_str.set('Type')


##### Random Label #####

randomLbl = Label(directionFrame, textvariable = randomStr)
randomLbl.pack()


##### Number Entry Box #####

number_input = Entry(directionFrame)
number_input.pack()

##### Enter Button #####

enterBtn = Button(directionFrame, text = 'Enter Guess', command = enterGuess)
enterBtn.pack()

##### Your Guess Label #####

yourGuessLbl = Label(directionFrame, textvariable = guess_var)
yourGuessLbl.pack()


##### GuessInt Label ######

guessIntLbl = Label(directionFrame, textvariable = guess_str)
guessIntLbl.pack()

##### Random Label ######
randomNumLbl = Label(directionFrame, textvariable = random_str)
randomNumLbl.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using `set` to begin with? `set` is a separate data type. Just assign using equals, i.e. `a = b`.

Comment: `randomNum` (the global `IntVar`, not the local in `randomize()`) is never changed, and not attached to any widget, so it continues to have the default value of 0.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama That's a method that sets the held value afaik.

Comment: You should simplify your code to use only one set of tkinter variables instead of multiple sets to reduce the error of using wrong variables for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared many tkinter variables that confuse you to use a wrong ones for comparison.

Actually using only two tkinter variables is enough:

- `randomNum` for random generated number
- `guessNum` for user guess number

```py
from random import randint
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Guess Number Final')
root.geometry('500x500')

directionFrame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200, highlightbackground='red', highlightthickness=3)
directionFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, ipadx=20, ipady=20)

randomNum = StringVar(value='Number')
guessNum = StringVar(value='')


def randomize():
    randomNum.set(randint(0,10))


def enterGuess():
    ok = randomNum.get() == guessNum.get().strip()
    resultLabel['text'] = f'Your guess is {"right" if ok else "wrong"}.'


##### Random Button #####

randomBtn = Button(directionFrame, text='Random Number', command=randomize)
randomBtn.pack()

##### Random Label #####

randomLbl = Label(directionFrame, textvariable=randomNum)
randomLbl.pack()

##### Number Entry Box #####

number_input = Entry(directionFrame, textvariable=guessNum)
number_input.pack()

##### Enter Button #####

enterBtn = Button(directionFrame, text='Enter Guess', command=enterGuess)
enterBtn.pack()

##### Result Label #####
resultLabel = Label(directionFrame, text='Your guess is ...')
resultLabel.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
randomNum = randint(0,10)
```

creates a new local variable `randomNum` and assigns it to a regular Python `int` value.  The original `randomNum` in the outer scope is still a default `IntVar` with a value of zero.  What I think you want to do is:

```
randomNum.set(randint(0, 10))
```

i.e. set the `IntVar` you created to point to a new random int.